# Create a 'Call Function' Table with Different Members

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers, stdmap

I'm trying to create a table that will call a general function from a general member. I'm trying to make a table of hotkeys, so when it identifies a certain key is pressed it will call the specific function on the specific object.

I have created an object (hotKeyCommand) that stores a pointer to a void function, and a template to the pointer of the object to call the function from. Then I have a map that looks like this:

```
//hotKeyCommand.cpp
template<class callObjectPointer> class hotKeyCommand
{
...
typedef void(*hotKeyFunc)();
hotKeyFunc commandFunction;
callObjectPointer objectToCall;

//hotKeyConfig.cpp
std::map<unsigned int, hotKeyCommand> hotKeyList;
```

I'm wondering how to interface with the hotKeyList variable to do this. Ideally I could just call hotKeyList[someID].execute() and it would execute the function to the appropriate object, but I run into lots of syntax errors based on not giving hotKeyList a template of which objects to use.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since `hotKeyCommand` is a template class, you need to provide the template parameter when you declare `hotKeyList`:

```
std::map<unsigned int, hotKeyCommand<float>> hotKeyList;
```

Then you can call the function as:

```
hotKeyList[someKey].commandFunction();
```

Note that your function doesn't take any parameters, and it's not a member function, so it doesn't have any access to the corresponding `hotKeyList[someKey].objectToCall` member.